# Ways round the \r function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Whenever I'm coding, I find I need to use `\r` quite often. And for some reason, it's ignored entirely. I'm working with Mac OS Catalina at the moment. If anyone has solutions for code where instead of using `\r` I can use something else which is compatible with my device. (I will be moving to Windows 10 very soon)
Some examples may be I wish to delete a printed line and replace it with something else.
The output might be something like this:

```
Hello
how are you?
```

The output I aim for is:
`Hello, **wait one second**`
And after the one second:
`how are you?`
simply replaces the `Hello` because the carriage return was used.

But the code I used had a `\r` in it. It's totally ignored. I also had this issue when I used a single-iterating `for i in range()` string which contained `'(Hello'+'\r')` or even using `print` or `sys.stdout.write` which contained `(Hello, end='\r')`. None of these worked. Then I removed the `\r` and found it had the same results. Why is `\r` ignored and is there a way to clear a line of print without using `\r`?

Comment: `\r` doesn't delete anything; it is simply interpreted by a terminal to move the cursor to the beginning of the line, at which point subsequent output might overwrite what's already on the screen. For the output you want, you should be using `\n` instead.

Comment: This is for deleting a line, right? Because I'm quite sure `\n` simply executes new-line function which I don't want.

Comment: Suggest you show some code, with the actual and desired output.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You could try something like `print('hello', end='')` followed by `print('\rHow are you?')`. The `end=""` is to prevent `print` from adding a line feed at the end of the printed text.

Comment: I'm looking for solutions which don't use `\r` I'm afraid because on my device they are simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This code bellow works fine for me, can you try it too?

```py
print('Hello!', end='\r')
print('How Are you?')
```

About the `for i in range()`, if you are trying something like that

```py
for i in range(10):
    print('Hello'+'\r')
```

this doesn't work because `print()` function by default ends to an `\n` so the string will look like `Hello\r\n` so what you need to do is to prevent that by adding the keyword argument `end=''` so it will look like

```py
for i in range(10):
    print('Hello'+'\r', end='')
```

or better

```py
for i in range(10):
    print('Hello', end='\r')
```

but this will look like it doesn't print nothing, that's because we need to add a newline after the iteration because the terminal prompt is gonna "sit" on top of the `Hello` because it ended with the `\r`, so the code would look like:

```py
for i in range(10):
    print('Hello', end='\r')
else:
    print()
```

**EDIT**: BTW `\r` doesn't delete the line, it places the cursor at the start of the line. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)

Hope that makes sense and helps!

~ PanTrakX

Comment: One: I'm aware of the functions of `\r`. Two: As I've specified in my question, the `\r` does not work for me in any situation. Just to be sure I will try it.

Comment: OK, I've tested the code. Sadly, it has spammed 'Hello' 10 times. As I explained, the `\r` does not work, it is simply ignored. I have asked for ways to return carriage without `\r` as it is ignored.

Comment: Then it looks like it's not a python problem but a terminal/shell problem!